# How to set the user data folder with Microsoft.Maui.Controls.WebView [ Windows ]

Tags: maui, webview2

How can the WebView2 folder location be set for a Microsoft.Maui.Controls.WebView ?

I see no obvious way to use the Xamarin WebView2 solution via a CoreWebView2Environment.

I know there is a possibility to do so via the Registry

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\WebView2\UserDataFolder

and also via an environment variable WEBVIEW2_USER_DATA_FOLDER

but I would prefer to not do it this way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For MAUi, windows platform using Windows UI Library (WinUI) 3. [In the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/user-data-folder?tabs=winui3#the-default-udf-location), WinUI 3 can only use the default UDF location, the default UDF location is the ApplicationData\LocalFolder subfolder in the package's folder.

Comment: That means you cannot install the application 'for everyone' ... doesn't it ?

Comment: If your app was installed per-user, you should probably create one UDF per user. Forr more details you can check this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/user-data-folder?tabs=winui3#persisting-user-data-folders-if-multiple-users-use-your-app-repeatedly

Comment: do you found solution?